# Differential equation given a solution

Tags: analysis

Just consider the equation of a siluroid in polar coordinates, that is

$\rho=4n\cos(\theta)\cos(2\theta)$

I am looking for a pure differential equation in $\dot\rho$ and $\ddot\rho$ whose solution is the given equation. By pure differential equation I mean an equation that does NOT contain $\theta$. For example

$\ddot\rho-2\dot\rho=0$

is pure, whereas

$\ddot\rho-2\dot\rho=cos(\theta)$

is not. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No linear differential equation uses only $\varrho$ and the first and second derivatives $\dot\varrho$ and $\ddot\varrho=\varrho^{(2)}$. If one can use higher derivatives, try
$$\varrho^{(4)}+10\varrho^{(2)}+9\varrho=0$$